# What is the best way to remove repeatable scripts from Flyway Migrations

Tags: flyway

I am currently using the Flyway Command Line tool to manage our scripts which will be invoked via our release process triggered from our CI Build server.

The issue is I have 274 repeatable migrations covering package specs, package bodies, functions, procedures, views and materialised views.

When I run migrate everything works as expected with migrations executing followed by any changed repeatable migrations but lets say in the next release we want to delete a object which one of the repeatable migrations maintains. For example, we want to remove the repeatable script that defined ProcedureOne (ie R__ProcedureOne.sql).

To do this I would have a new migration script (V3.1.5.1.01__DropProcedureOne.sql) but I would also remove the repeatable migration script so the object isn't created again and maintained.

However, executing flyway info shows the R__ProcedureOne.sql script with the status of MISSING.

While I agree it is missing it is a deliberate action to have it deleted as it is no longer required opposed to being misplaced.

I am aware of the migrate option ignoreMissingMigrations but i think using this introduces risk and could mask genuine missing files.

What is the general guidance on how best to remove a repeatable scripts?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you simply keep the file but make it empty (ie zero bytes). Alternatively have a comment in the file that explains that the object it represents has been removed.

As for actually removing it, another option from what you suggested could be to update the repeatable migration to remove itself then update again to zero length. This has the advantage of being able to be replayed into an empty database; since repeatable migrations are applied after versioned the procedure in your example won't exist to be dropped. The disadvantage is running two migrations.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

A couple of interesting options. I do like having the independent versioned script to drop the procedure but not sure exactly how i feel about just leaving the repeatable script there for eternity even if it is blank. t just feels like leaving clutter behind.

What's the feeling on editing the contents of the schema_version table? The drop proc script could remove all references to the repeatable script (not tried this so dont know if this would work)

Comment: Do you have a need to reproduce the database by running scripts from version 1? If not then you can take some liberties with the history kept in the schema_version table. I would not recommend this as you lose the audit history that flyway creates for you. 
You would need to experiment with how to achieve it as Flyway may lock the schema_version table whilst running. I would suggest copying the records to another table to keep the history